# Android trying to use Debug.startMethodTracing("trace") - trace file is created but it is empty

Tags: android

Im testing on a real device
I have the required permission in the AndroidManifest

Before I start a networking operation that logs the user in to the system, I have this line of code

```
Debug.startMethodTracing("trace");
```

and right after its done, before the method returns, I have this line of code:

```
Debug.stopMethodTracing();
```

I can find the file on the SD card, but it is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, you might have found an answer by now. If that's the case then please don't hesitate to post the answer.

The fact that the trace file is created but empty means that there is no "flush" into the file, meaning that stopMethodTracing might not be called.
In order to detect why this is, you might want to widen the scope of your trace capture in order to prove that it indeed works.
My advice would be to start tracing in your activity's onCreate method and add an entry in LogCat.

```
Log.d("onCreate", "Start tracing in onCreate");
Debug.startMethodTracing("trace-file");
```

Then you wind up in the activity's onDestroy

```
Log.d("onDestroy", "onDestroy called");
Debug.stopMethodTracing();
```

Remember that calls to onDestroy() are not guaranteed (although a call to LogCat might be enough to trigger it) so you might stop the trace collection in onStop() rather.

If the above works, try to reduce the scope of the trace and investigate further.

Hope this helps